# Can't get value from javascript array using variable in brackets

Tags: javascript, variables, multidimensional-array

```
function swapProd()
{
var image = document.getElementById("prodImage");
var dropd = document.getElementById("prodDrop");
image.src = "images/ej/" + prodArrJS[dropd.value][2] + ".jpg";
}
```

the function is on an onchange in a form dropdown where "prodDrop" is the option field. "prodArrJS" is a 2d array. It's not accepting "dropd.value".

Comment: Well, what does it do? Does it give an error? Not do anything? Blow up your computer? Make waffles fall from the sky? Please be more specific.

Comment: test your dropd.value using alert. either it is not reading any collection or it doesn't not have value at index 2

Comment: Sorry. It doesn't do anything in this dimension, and stops the function. The dropd.value is working if I display it on a field, for example. And the array is working if I put a number in the brackets instead of dropd.value.

Comment: I don't know if this has anything to do with it: the prodArrJS array was created like this: var prodArrJS = <?php echo json_encode($products);?>

Answer (score 1):

check this 
 [demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r6Fus/964/),

I have added values to two dimensional array from two dropdown lists

```
array[0][1]=[document.getElementById("mySelect").value],["hello"];
```

or

```
array.push([document.getElementById("mySelect").value],[document.getElementById("second").value]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to get the value from the array, not to put one into it.

Answer (score 0):

The '.value' property returns the contents of the input as a string and unless your 'prodArrJS' is an Object (which I have a suspicion it isn't), your trying to access a value at an index using a string. Try doing 'parseInt(dropd.value)'.

Comment: Just going to point out here that _all keys are Strings_, meaning `['foo']['0']` is `"foo"`

Comment: Thanks, but parseInt is not doing anything either.

Comment: Yes, the key works as string or as number.Still, the document.getElementById("x").value

Comment: GOT TIMEOUT ON LAST COMMENT.Yes, the key works with strings or numbers as well (if that is the case). Still, the document.getElementById("x").value is not working within the array brackets. Not as parseInt() or Number(), or by assigning it to another variable and using that either.